# Maven - attach artifact with Maven descriptor files

Tags: maven

For performance reasons I need to create a new EAR artifact beside a WAR archive **without using multiple modules projekt**. The EAR will contain the WAR (in the `/web` sub-directory) and the static `application.xml` file.

All I need to generate in the non-static way is Java classes and **Maven descriptor files** (`META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml` and `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties`).

With classes there is no big deal, but how to generate and attach the Maven descriptor files to the new EAR?

This works well, but the Maven descriptor files are not generated inside the EAR archive.

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
<properties>
  <compile.dir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</compile.dir>
  <ear.zip>${project.build.directory}/my-archive.ear</ear.zip>
</properties>
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create-EAR-archive</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <target>
              <!-- copy webapp files -->
              <copy todir="${compile.dir}/web">
                  <fileset dir="src/main/webapp" />
              </copy>
              <!-- copy classes -->
              <copy todir="${compile.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes">
                  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
              </copy>
              <!-- copy application.xml -->
              <copy todir="${compile.dir}">
                  <fileset dir="src/main/resources" includes="META-INF/application.xml" />
              </copy>
              <!-- copy some big files -->
              ...
              <!-- zip EAR -->
              <zip destfile="${ear.zip}" basedir="${compile.dir}" />
            </target>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-EAR-artifact</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>${ear.zip}</file>
                        <type>ear</type>
                        <classifier>exploded</classifier>
                    </artifact>                                
                </artifacts>
                <archive>
                  <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Make a separte maven project of packaging type ear, add the appropiate configuration to that module and use the dependency to the war, add maven-ear-plugin configuration to add the war and that's it...Not trying to do different things in one pom will be a mess....

Comment: I don't want to use a multiple projekt due to performance reasons.

Comment: First make it work than make it fast...clear separation of concern...Have you measured the difference in particular using antrun ???

Comment: Yes, the second "wrong" approach is working with 500m without trouble, the first "correct" approach is unstable even with 3g...

Comment: What do you mean by `500m` and `3g`??

Comment: I mean the JVM parameter -Xmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the war package phase into another phase before the prepare-package phase, then there is a complete WAR archive containing the maven descriptor files. So it means, all the data are ready when the EAR archive is prepared.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>war</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>                    
</plugin>
```

The archive unzip and use in the prepare-package phase as before:

```
<!-- unzip the war -->
<unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war" dest="${project.build.directory}/war-exploded" />                                

<!-- move the war content -->
<move todir="${compile.dir}/web">
    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/war-exploded" />
</move>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to have a multi module project.

A parent like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
        <myproject.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</myproject.version>
  </properties>

  <name>ear-example</name>
  <modules>
    <module>example-ear</module>
    <module>example-war</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

A war as you have, and an ear project:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>example-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Then just add any files you need to the src/main/application directory in the ear project and they will appear in the top level of your ear file.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to, my intentions are to avoid this for the performace reasons.

Comment: @TomasTulka sorry to hear this is not what you want, this is the way it should be done.  What are your performance concerns?

Comment: I did it this in the correct way, but the problem is, that the web app is pretty big and the maven ear plugin is unstable because of Java heap space. The problem is, that I can't set more memory on the build-server. My solution works well regarding the performace, but the maven descriptor files are missing (and I need them for a later integration). Thanks for any tip!

Comment: I'm not sure, how the maven ear plugin works, but it must be extracting and copying the included data, which is memory and space costly. That's the reason I want to avoid it.